# How to call a javascript function of the page from chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to call this js fuctnion `MC.showLevelUp(100,94,95)` from a chrome extension.

I don't have experience with chrome extensions so i don't know how to do that.
I tried to do it as usual:

```
document.getElementById("skin_tRex").addEventListener("click", MC.showLevelUp(100,94,95))
```

but obviously this does not work.

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong and how should i do it! Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. addEventListener expects a function-type parameter, not a function-call 2. where's that MC.showLevelUp defined? your content script? the page script?

Comment: The function is defined by the website and i want to call it from the extension

Comment: See [Building a Chrome Extension - Inject code in a page using a Content script](//stackoverflow.com/a/9517879) and [How to access the webpage DOM rather than the extension page DOM?](//stackoverflow.com/a/4532567)

Comment: Exactly i want to access the function from the webpage but call the function from a button which is on the extension

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In chrome extensions, the code in run in a sandboxed environment, so any event listeners won't apply to the main page.

From my understanding, you want a button click to trigger and run a function on the web page. The best way to do this would be to inject code into the page.

```
document.getElementById("skin_tRex").addEventListener("click", runScriptOnPage)

function runScriptOnPage() {
    var actualCode = 'MC.showLevelUp(100,94,95)';
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.textContent = actualCode;
    (document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
    script.remove();
}
```